# App doesn't progress in Validate App in Windows App Certification Kit in UWP?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I am creating an application using Xamarin.Forms but when I try to verify my app using Windows App Certification Kit it fails on `Platform version launch`.

I also try with make new sample app and in that it works proper and display result pass.

Is there any one who knows this issue and step to stop this can you please suggest or what should I have to check in my application.

I attached screenshot for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: You can try to upload the file to the site if you think it is OK, WACK is not 100% reliable. Especially if it doesn't complete certification at all.

Comment: @IvanIčin Is there any other method to check that our UWP package is proper or not we have to verify once before publish to live

Comment: The app is checked by Microsoft both automatically and by human. You may also run a beta test on the Store before going live

Comment: @IvanIčin Thanks for response. Can you please guide for beta test?

Comment: @DeepSoni Beta test should start a new question and you can refer to [Beta testing and targeted distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/beta-testing-and-targeted-distribution) and [Beta testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/beta-testing)

Comment: Thanks @BarryWang-MSFT it helps me a lot